# Percentile calculation for binary attributes

Tags: probability, distributions, quantiles

Assume I have the following dataset:

```
building_id    is_business    is_resedential    is_commercial
12             1              0                 0    
13             0              1                 0   
14             0              0                 1
15             1              0                 0
16             0              0                 1
17             0              0                 1
```

Data description: each category can take 0/1, and each building has one category. So the proportion of business categories is 2/6, residential is 1/6, and commercial is 3/6.

I have a weird question, but I would like to hear your opinion and the possibility of how to interpret it. Does it make sense to calculate the `percentile 25, percentile 50, and percentile 75` for each category? Assume we got `percentile25=0.0, percentile50=0.2, and percentile75=0.4` for the business category, how would we interpret it?

Comment: In a sense, you will always get $0$ for the `percentile25` on that data for all three indicators.  So your question might be better asked about  `percentile75`, which in R would give $0.75$ for `is_business`, and you need to interpret this as an interpolation estimate from a sample (in this particular case, using an R default type $7$ interpolation method as described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a large dataset of buildings where $1/3$ of them are business, then:

- the 75th and 50th percentiles of the business variable would be 1;
- the 25th percentile of the business variable would be 0.

So yes, percentiles for 0-1 variables are meaningful. For a small sample with substantial uncertainty about the percentiles, it might even be meaningful to get other percentiles by interpolation which are neither 0 nor 1.

However, I can’t think of a context for a 0-1 variable whose 50th percentile is 0.2 and whose 75th percentile is 0.4: I don’t know any interpolation method for percentiles which could lead to that result. So that particular example may lack a meaningful interpretation; it looks more like an error.